# How to search backwards with regex on multilne string in python

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way of doing the following:

I have a python script that reads an entire file into a single string.  Then, given the location of a token of interest, I'd like to find the string index of the beginning of the line given that token.

```
file_str = read_file("foo.txt")
token_pos = re.search("token",file_str).start()

#this does not work, as str.rfind does not take regex, and you cannot specify re.M:
beginning_of_line = file_str.rfind("^",0,token_pos)
```

I could use a greedy regex to find the last beginning of line, but this has to be done many times, so I'm concerned that I don't want to read the whole file on each iteration.   Is there a good way to do this?

----------------- EDIT ----------------

I tried to post as simple of a question, but it looks like more details are required.  Here's a better example of one of the things I'm trying to do:

```
file_str = """
{
   blah {  
      {} {{}  "string with unmatched }" }
   }
}"""
```

I happen to know where the opening an closing positions of `blah`'s braces are.   I need to get the lines between the braces (non-inclusive).   So, given the position of the closing brace, I need to find the beginning of the line containing it.  I'd like to do something akin to a reverse regex to find it.   I can, of course, write a special function to do this, but I was thinking there would be some more python-ish way of going about it.   To further complicate things, I would have to do this several times per file, and the file string can potentially change between iterations, so pre-indexing doesn't really work either...

Comment: What do you think of this to get the indexes all at once? `[ file_str.rfind(string) for string in re.findall('^.*token.*', file_str, re.M) ]`

Comment: There is no `re.find()` Did you mean `re.search()`?

Comment: Yes, sorry, fixed

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"I need to find the **beginning of the line** containing it"_? Do you mean all of the line containing the token up until the token begins?

Comment: "So, given the position of the closing brace, I need to find the beginning of the line containing it." How do you determine which closing bracket matches with which starting bracket - without having the context of the whole file, that is not possible.

Comment: "To further complicate things, I would have to do this several times per file, and the file string can potentially change between iterations" Sorry, but given this, it seems you have a mission impossible on your hands :D

Comment: @PärtJohanson Most likely several times because of different tokens? MI seems a bit pessimistic :)

Comment: Another question: _"I happen to know where the opening an closing positions of `blah`'s braces are"_ What does the _know_ mean here: Do you know the position in the string?

Comment: @Timus if it's for different token then not. But if the task is to parse multiple different files somehow as "one" and match opening and closing brackets in there somehow, then the whole thing is ill defined.

Comment: I know the string indexes of all braces, based on some metadata associated with the file.   (also note, when the string is modified, my local copy of indexes are also updated so these are kept up to date).   @PärtJohanson -- no, I am only processing one file at a time.  All lines are consolidated to a single string in the file.

Comment: Okay, let's say `file_str = "abcd\nefg}h"` and you know the token (`"}"`) is at position `8`. Then you could do `file_str.rfind("\n", 0, 8) + 1` to get `5`, the beginning position of the respective line - or is that too simple?

Comment: Ack -- now I feel stupid!   I somehow hadn't considered using the string `"\n"` instead of the regex `"^"`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of matching just the keyword, match *everything from the start of the line to the keyword*. You could use `re.finditer()`<sup>[docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer)</sup> to get an iterator that keeps yielding matches as it finds them.

```
file_str = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit amet.
Vestibulum vestibulum mollis enim, eu tristique est rhoncus et.
Curabitur sem nisi, ornare eu pellentesque at, interdum at lectus.
Phasellus molestie, turpis id ornare efficitur, ex tellus aliquet ipsum, vitae ullamcorper tellus diam a velit.
Nulla eget eleifend nisl.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Nullam finibus, velit non euismod faucibus, dolor orci maximus lacus, sed mattis nisi erat eget turpis.
Maecenas ut pharetra lorem.
Curabitur nec dui sed velit euismod bibendum.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Pellentesque tempor dolor at placerat aliquet.
Duis laoreet, est vitae tempor porta, risus leo ullamcorper risus, quis vestibulum massa orci ut felis.
In finibus purus ac nulla congue mattis.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Duis efficitur dui ac nisi lobortis, a bibendum felis volutpat.
Aenean consectetur diam at risus hendrerit, in vestibulum erat porttitor.
Quisque fringilla accumsan neque, sed efficitur nunc tristique maximus.
Maecenas gravida lectus et porttitor ultrices.
Nam lobortis, massa et porta vulputate, nulla turpis maximus sapien, sit amet finibus libero mauris eu sapien.
Donec sollicitudin vulputate neque, in tempor nisi suscipit quis.
"""

keyword = "amet"
for match_obj in re.finditer(f"^.*{keyword}", file_str, re.MULTILINE):
    beginning_of_line = match_obj.start()
    print(beginning_of_line, match_obj)
```

Which gives:

```
0 <re.Match object; span=(0, 60), match='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscin>
331 <re.Match object; span=(331, 357), match='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'>
566 <re.Match object; span=(566, 592), match='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'>
815 <re.Match object; span=(815, 841), match='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'>
1129 <re.Match object; span=(1129, 1206), match='Nam lobortis, massa et porta vulputate, nulla tur>
```

Note that the first line gets matched only once even though it contains two `amet`s because we do a greedy match on `.` so the first `amet` on the line is consumed by the `.*`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need use regex to find the beginning of lines with the token

This will iterate the file line by line, create the string foo with the file's content and record where the newlines are in list named line_pos_with_token

```
token = "token"
foo = ''
line_pos_with_token = []

with open("foo.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        if token in line:
            line_pos_with_token.append(len(foo))
        foo += line

print(line_pos_with_token)
```

Comment: I'm not actually looking for `token` -- I'm looking for the beginning of line preceding `token`.   Notice that there are many, many instances of `token` in the file (in fact, it can appear multiple times in one line).

Comment: Are you interested in all of the lines with the token? And how big is the file?

Comment: A file will typically be over 1000 lines long (and I have to process 300 of them each time I do a build of my system).   I'm only interested in a small subset of the lines with the token.   Another part of the program figures out where the tokens of interest are and then I have to extract a string between another given point and the beginning of the line containing the token.